# Does bit dungeon ever end?

Tags: bit-dungeon

I've played through to level 25 with no sign of the game ending.  Is there even an end to the game?  Or does it go on forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Bit Dungeon is an endless game and there is no ending in-game. I think you will beat every variation of bosses at some time though.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ending. If you find a white orb at lvl 50+, you get transported to an empty dungeon. There is a boss. After you defeat the boss, you see your wife and you can end the game by walking up to her. Or you can ignore her by going around.

Comment: This directly conflicts with the other answer.  Do you have a source for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently at level 167 and finished my second time round (dark world completed twice) and as everybody else says, doesnt look like its ending any time soon, but everything is repeated after the dark world, same bosses etc, but the weapons are slightly more powerful and equal with the enemies

Answer (score 0):

There is an ending, same as the pic shown above... If you buy a soul (blue heart thingy) or get it somewhere (after one of the bosses there is a stone crypt thingy that dropped it), you can click on it and it'll take you to another world, after beating the boss there you can join your waifu's spirit

Answer (score 0):

To fight Soul Collector to "finish" the game you have to get a soul. It's on the bottom left. It's a white heart; all you gotta do is click on it. You'll be transported and have to fight the Soul Collector. Otherwise, the game goes on forever. Btw you can get the Soul very early in the game by buying it for 1k Black coins or just randomly finding it. Completed the game on the 27th Room.

Answer (score -2):

[image: Ending screen]

THis is the ending screen of Bit Dungeon 2

Comment: How do you get to this ending? It seems more like a Credits page than an ending to the game...